# Cannot access to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I cannot access to my JSON object.

```
// test.json
{
    "greet": [
        "hi"
    ]
}
```

Firstly I return JSON object with:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
```

It returns the right JSON object.

[the JSON object in console in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2YtG.png)

But when I want to access to object `greet` with:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText["greet"]));
```

It returns:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Why?

Comment: The `["greet"]` goes **after** the close `)` of `JSON.parse()`, not within.

Comment: @zero298 is saying `console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText)["greet"]);` prints "hi"

Comment: There is no such thing as a _JSON Object_. JSON is always a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
let parsedJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText)

console.log(parsedJson["greet"])
```

Because `this.responseText` is a string and you have to convert it to an object first with `JSON.parse()`.

Hopefully, this helps.